# Is it possible to host grpc api and asp.net web api on same port?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, microservices, grpc, hosting

I have a asp.net web microservice, now I want to include grpc concept in some microservices. Is it possible to host rest web Api's and grpc Api's on same port? If not what's the correct way of using grpc with web Api's ? Should I create 2 separate applications for web Api and grpc or just host them on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same host process, then you *might* use the same port.
There's also [gRPC-Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/grpcweb?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which could potentially be easier to use.

Additionally, if you ever decide you want to separate the concepts and have HTTP API and gRPC separately, but on the same port - you can use Nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks @jTinkers . Is it possible to reroute the grpc requests using ocelet ?

Comment: @Learner No clue.